# Event handling in nested compositeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am using the same structure as explained in the answers for this question -- > [How to handle nested CompositeView using Backbone.Marionette?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575101/how-to-handle-nested-compositeview-using-backbone-marionette/32787508?noredirect=1#comment53426646_32787508) 
to render my composite views and Item view. My Item view consists of LI tag. I want to handle click event for this Itemview. I am trying my code as below :**which is not working** The same events code snippet If I write in my first composite view, It get's triggered. But events do not get triggered in ItemView. Please help.

```
var topNavMenuView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
           tagName :'li',
           className:'dropdown',
           template : _.template(topNavMenuItemTemplate) ,

           initialize:function(options){
           console.log("initialize");
            this.id=options.menuCode;
          },
          events: {
             'click li' : function(event){
                  alert('click');
              },
             'click ' : function(event){
                             alert('click');
             }
            }

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

View [`events`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) should return events hash like this

```
events: {
    'click': 'onClick'
},
onClick: function(){
    alert('click');
}
```